# Need a Formula to add the current date in a specific cell that data is added to another

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that has to have data entered into it each and every day

What i would like is that when Data is entered into lets say A1 that the current date is put in G1.

And every day when data is added to any cell in column A that the corresponding cell in column G will add the date

Comment: This cannot be done with a forumula. You need VBA to detect a cell change. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/213612/how-to-run-a-macro-when-certain-cells-change-in-excel

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then'Enter content in Column A
        If Target = "" Then
            Target.Offset(0, 6) = ""
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 6) = Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd")'Record date in Column G
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Lee, this code has error OBJECT REQUIRED, in Row says If Target.Colum .